# How to make sure that "tidy" library only corrects those tags which are required.?

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, warnings, tidy

Currently I'm passing my xml string as an input to tidy's functions.

```
string validateXml(const std::string &html)
{
    // init a tidy document
    TidyDoc tidy_doc=tidyCreate();
    TidyBuffer output_buffer= {0};

    // configure tidy
    // the flags tell tidy to output xml and disable warnings
    bool config_success=tidyOptSetBool(tidy_doc,TidyXmlOut,yes)
                        && tidyOptSetBool(tidy_doc,TidyQuiet,yes)
                        && tidyOptSetBool(tidy_doc,TidyNumEntities,yes)
                        && tidyOptSetBool(tidy_doc,TidyShowWarnings,no);

    int tidy_rescode=-1;

    // parse input
    if(config_success){
        tidy_rescode=tidyParseString(tidy_doc,html.c_str());
    }

    // process html
    if(tidy_rescode>=0){
        tidy_rescode=tidySaveBuffer(tidy_doc,&output_buffer);
    }

    if(tidy_rescode<0){
        throw("tidy has a error: "+tidy_rescode);
    }

    std::string result=(char *)output_buffer.bp;
    tidyBufFree(&output_buffer);
    tidyRelease(tidy_doc);

    return result;
}
```

I just want it to validate only those parts which are required, withot providing the complete HTML structure.

And also how to hide warnings which I get using `xmlParseMemory` before validating an invalid xml string?

```
s = validateXml(s);
doc = xmlParseMemory(s.c_str(), s.length());
```

the above is ok in case of invalid xml string, but how to hide warnings when I use

```
doc = xmlParseMemory(s.c_str(), s.length());
s = validateXml(s);
```